# running scripts using SSH Tunnel mac

Tags: macos, ssh, putty, tunnel

I have got a SSH tunnel setup using Coccinellida tunnel manager but I really can't work out how the hell I run the scripts I need to!?!? its says it is connected but I have no text area to write the directory of the scripts?

I usually use 'Putty' for windows for this process and when I use that I just connect and type the directory of the scripts and they run.

apologies this stuff is a little over my head :-S

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So the scripts you want run is on a remote server, firstly you have to connect to the server via ssh, you can do it with the default Terminal app or iTerm: ssh username@serverip. This ssh connection process is the done by Putty as on windows.